# Accessing nested data via Handlebars.js using 'this' as second property value

Tags: javascript, json, nested, handlebars.js

I’m having trouble accessing nested data via handlebars. I've searched similar questions but none of them involve using the value of 'this' as a property name.

Here's the data:

```
var activity_groups = ["foo", "bar", "blargh"]; //this array is generated dynamically and may have any or all of these elements

var hb_data = {
    "activity_groups"   : activity_groups,
    "img_alt" : {
        "foo"       : "foo alt",
        "bar"       : "bar alt",
        "blargh"    : "blargh alt"
    },
    "img_src" : {
        "foo"       : "foo src",
        "bar"       : "bar src",
        "blargh"    : "blargh src"
    },
    "title" : {
        "foo"       : "foo title",
        "bar"       : "bar title",
        "blargh"    : "blargh title"
    },
    "desc" : {
        "foo"       : "foo desc",
        "bar"       : "bar desc",
        "blargh"    : "blargh desc"
    }
}
```

the template:

```
{{#each activity_groups}}
<div data-type="{{this}}">
    <img class="activity_group_selector_img" alt="{{../img_alt.this}}" src="{{../img_src.this}}" />
    <span>{{../title.this}}</span>
    <div class="activity_group_selector_description">{{../desc.this}}</div>
</div>
{{/each}}
```

The problem is with these:

```
{{../img_alt.this}}
{{../img_src.this}}
{{../title.this}}
{{../desc.this}}
```

which throw an Uncaught Error: Invalid path

Is there a way to use the value of 'this' to access the nested data?

I’m open to entirely different solutions, but I’d really like to know how to do it using the current model.

Comment: For instance, I'd like the {{../img_alt.this}} expression to get the value at img_alt.foo, img_alt.bar, and img_alt.blargh for each respective loop through activity_groups.

So first "foo alt", then "bar alt", then "blargh alt".

And the same intention with the other expressions that use .this

Comment: First id ensure that the ../var is returning the correct value, then try bracket notation of ../var[this], and then try (..var/)[this] maybe.

Comment: The **../var** is returning the correct value, but unfortunately neither of your suggestions worked. **Parse error** for both.

Answer (score 0):

Create a helper:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('getProperty', function(context, key) {
    return context[key];
});
```

Example of usage:

```
{{getProperty ../img_alt this}}
```